# Getting enum value from user

Tags: c, enums

I wonder how it is possible to get the enum value into the enum variable "today" from the user and not by initializing it like in the given example.
do I have to use a scanf to string array and make today = string array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum week{ sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday};
int main(){
enum week today;
today=wednesday;
printf("%d day",today+1);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a plain `enum`. A classic trick is to augment the enum with an `array of const char*` in which you store the names in the same order as the enum. You then can use an enum value as an index into the array to retrieve the corresponding `string` value.

```
// enum to string
printf("%s\n", week_str[MONDAY]);
// string to enum
const char* input = "tuesday"; // get this from scanf or something
size_t length = strlen(input);
int i;
int found = -1;
for (i = 0; i <= WEDNESDAY; i++) {
  if(strncmp(input, week_str[i], length) == 0) {
    found = i;
    break;
  }
}
printf("Found: %i", found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes more or less. Enums are represented internally as ints and the names of the enum type is lost during compilation.

Your program will print

```
4 day
```

If you want to preserve the names of the days you must have a string array such as

```
const char *days[] =
{
  "sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", ...
} ;
```

and do the conversion yourself. For example :

```
printf ("The day is %s", days[monday]) ;
```

will print

```
The day is monday
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum week{ sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday };

char * EnumToString(int day)    {
    switch (day)    {
        case sunday: return "sunday";
        case monday: return "monday";
        case tuesday: return "tuesday";
        case wednesday: return "wednesay";
        case thursday: return "thursday";
        case friday: default: return "friday";
    }
}

enum week StringToEnum(char * day)  {

    // To not be case sensitive
    for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++){
      day[i] = tolower(day[i]);
    }
    switch (day)    {
        case "sunday": return sunday;
        case "monday": return monday;
        case "tuesday": return tuesday;
        case "wednesday": return wednesay;
        case "thursday": return thursday;
        case "friday": default: return friday;
    }
}

int main(){
    enum week today;
    today=wednesday;
    printf("%dth day is %s",today+1, EnumToString(today+1));
    return 0;
}
```

It will print :

```
4th day is thursday
```

Comment: This can me **heavily** optimized. The C standard assures that the numeric value of `sunday` is 0, that of `monday` is 1 and so on.

Comment: You mean to replace enum values by their number into the functions? But if you want later to add or remove values in the enumeration, you'll have to recode the entire function.

Comment: No, that's worse, it's actually the same thing but it's error prone and less readably. Look at my and pmr's answer, that's what I meant.

Comment: You method is of course more readable, but if he wanted to do like printf("The day is %s", days[getchar()-48]), there is a risk to be out of bound of the array

Comment: The point is not getting rid of your EnumToString and StringToEnum functions but implementing them differently by having a lookup table. It's basically combining my and pmr's solutions.